# apache2 VirtualHost on a new port not working

Tags: apache, ubuntu, port, virtualhost, lamp

I just installed LAMP on my Ubuntu machine, and it works fine when I access it. I want to add a virtual host on another port, port 1337, that goes to the directory `/var/www/flag-1/`. In order to do this, I take the following steps:

1. `cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/`
2. Created a file `flag-1.conf`
3. Added contents:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:1337>
>     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
>     DocumentRoot /var/www/flag-1/
>     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
>     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

4. At the top of `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, after `Listen 80`, added `Listen 1337`
5. Enabled the vhost site by doing `a2ensite flag-1.conf`
6. Reloaded apache `service apache2 restart`

When I access the site with port 1337, it just loads indefinitely. The default port still works fine, and I don't have UFW enabled. No errors, nothing in `access.log` or `error.log` is outstanding.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out -- I was using Google Cloud Platform and they blocked port 1337, I just had to manually allow TCP through it.

If you're wondering, the command was

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-port-1337 --allow tcp:1337 --description="Allow port 1337 to be accessed"
```